# Header function not working for the log out and log in

Tags: php, session, header

Well I have have already read the [cannot modify header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

But still I'm getting the error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\web\librarian_menu.php:582)
```

This is my code , I don't know what i am doing wrong

```
<body>
<?php
    @session_start();
    require 'connect.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['lib']))
    {
        echo '<strong style="position:relative;top:25px; left:940px;">'.$_SESSION['lib'].'</strong>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('You need to login first')</script>";
        header('Location: quote.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['log_out']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['lib']);
        header('Location: quote.php');
    }
?>
.
.
.
```

Comment: remove white space if any after and before php tag ... and use exit; after header location

Comment: @ user1844933  Well i have already tried the white spaces  ,that is not working and the output sent  is on the first line `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

If what you posted above really is your code, then it is pretty obvious where the problem comes from. Just look at the first line of code right before your opening php tag:

```
<body>
<?php
@session_start();
require 'connect.php';
```

See the `<body>` tag? You output it before anything else. A similar issue exists within the `else` branch of the first conditional: *first* you echo some string, *then* you call the `header()` function. You simply must not output / echo anything prior to calling that `header()` function.

Note that such code *might* work, when the http server caches the preliminary output. But you have no guarantee for that. So you cannot rely on it. Apparently in your case that output is *not* cached, but sent before you cann the `header()` function.

The reason for this behaviour of php, for this issue is a simple one: http headers are *preceding* an http reply. Per definition there cannot be any content contained in a reply *before* the headers. So once php start to send any content it *must* close the headers and sent them first. If you try to add any additional headers afterwards php has no choice but to raise an error: sending simply is impossible within that reply.

You have to restructure your code to sent the headers prior to anything else. If that really is not possible, then you might want to take a look at "output buffering". It allows you to hold back any output and release it to the client only later, after having done whatever is required, for example defining additional http headers.

Any maybe a side note, just to make things crystal clear: with the message "Warning: Cannot modify header information..." php refers to the *http headers*, *not* to any html header tag you might use.

Comment: how `body` tag is affecting the header

Answer (score 0):

Before header function (such as session_start, header) you cannot output anything to the browser - remove echos and html tags like `<body>` from the code before `session_start()` or `header()`.

Read the first few lines of this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Well there is no html and echos before the header, as in the program above if the header part will be executed then echos will not be executed

Comment: but session_start is also header function